# what does "property with 'weak' attribute must be of object type" really mean?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this in my interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSTimeInterval *timeStamp;
```

Which my logic told me, I need a time stamp object, that only is going to be used by this class within the context of its instantiation, so "weak" seemed to be logical to me-- but XCode tells me "property with 'weak' attribute must be of object type"...  If I just do:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval *timeStamp;
```

Then the error goes away, but I am not sure I understand why...

Comment: For those here because they get this message with what they think is actually an object type, rather than a value type: did you remember to #import the header for that type? I just got this error because I'd hooked up an IBOutlet for an ADBannerView in Xcode and foolishly forgot to `#import <iAd/iAd.h>` so that the code knew what an ADBannerView actually was...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that `NSTimeInterval` is a value type -- it's an alias for `double`, essentially (check NSDate.h for the typedef). The `weak` attribute only applies to objects that have a retain count (that is, anything that descends from `NSObject` or `NSProxy`).

As such, storing a pointer to `NSTimeInterval` is probably a mistake on your part. You will most likely never receive a pointer to an `NSTimeInterval` unless you're expected to write to a given address as an output to a function (probably a callback in such a case). That said, I'm not aware of any functions with `NSTimeInterval *` as a return type nor any that pass the same to a callback.

Comment: so the proper thing to do is just @property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval *timeStamp;  ?

Comment: @patrick: `@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval timeStamp;`. The `*` makes it a pointer, which you almost certainly don't want.

Comment: Anything that is a valid `CFTypeRef` may also (as of recent SDKs) be used with the `weak`, `strong`, `retain`, and `copy` keywords.

Comment: Does that apply to all Core Foundation types or just bridged types? I'm not sure, since it's not something I've looked into, but it's definitely worth knowing.

Comment: Bridging only works because NS-types are ObjC wrappers over CF-type objects, so in most cases, yes.  But honestly, why would you want a pointer to a value you don't need to store the address of (that and dealing with malloc and free when you don't have to is a pain).